# How to show the accreditation of a university abroad

Tags: graduate-admissions, accreditation

I live in the U.S but got my undergrad from a university in another country.
Now I have applied for Masters in the U.S and the department of graduate studies have requested this information from me, How do I provide it to them? What are they looking for?

Also: The university is [Sheikh Bahaei University](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheikh_Bahaei_University)

> Is the university where you obtained your undergraduate degree an
>   accredited institution?  That is, is it of a reasonable quality in
>   some quantifiable ways?

Comment: Does your university receive funding from the government, or is it a school recognized by an educational body in your country? Also, it might help to provide a country in this case.

Comment: @Compass Thanks, this is the university: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheikh_Bahaei_University

Comment: *Sheikh Bahaei University is governed according to educational regulations of the High Council of Cultural Revolution and the Ministry of Science, Research and Technology, the latter endorsing its credential degrees.* I'm not a lawyer, but this sounds like an accreditation. Ask your university to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various countries have different accrediting bodies. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_education_accreditation) has a nice overview.

From what you've written, it seems like they are looking for some information about what body (usually a private accrediting agency or a government ministry of education) your undergraduate institution is accredited by. To use a school near me as an example, I might say something like:

> Brooklyn College is accredited by the Middle States Commission on Higher Education, as stated [here](http://www.brooklyn.cuny.edu/bc/offices/avpbandp/ipra/middlestates.htm).  You can see Brooklyn College listed on the accrediting body's website, [here](http://www.msche.org/institutions_directory.asp?txtRange=b).

In your case, you can point them to [this page](http://www.shbu.ac.ir/About%20the%20university.php), which shows that the university is accredited by the Ministry of Science, Research and Technology of Iran (which is the government body that is responsible for accreditation of institutes of higher education in Iran).